# Android capture layout in app

Tags: android, xml, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to capture my app screen, not all of it only the linear layout.

atm I'm using this which I think should work, but IDK y it's not. It captures all the screen of the phone not only the linearlayout which I wants it to

```
    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
            View v1 = ll.getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

part of my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/Linear" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="60dp"
                     android:layout_height="60dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ll" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/lle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

atm it should capture the linearlayout which contains only 3imageviews and 2 textviews, but it captures all the xml or the screen.

Comment: What you could do is set some background color for each ``LinearLayout`` and ``RelativeLayout`` to see their area properly. I'm suspecting that setting layout_height="match_parent" for inner RelativeLayout causes the LinearLayout to grow whole screen high.

Comment: @harism nah thats not the problem here, it's that I need to capture the screen from <LinearLayout xx> to </LinearLayout xx> not all the screen. only the things between the xx LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are asking for the root view, which is "all the xml". Instead, you should be just using your `LinearLayout`:

```
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linear);
        ll.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bm = ll.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

by using this we can capture layout and save in to sd card.
`ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            l1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            img_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(l1.getDrawingCache());
            l1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
         }
      });
   }`